# What is the JS schema for power bi basic filter calculated fields

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I am new in Power Bi. I have a report in power bi service and I have integrated in ASP.Net MVC using javascript. I have few calculated fields in my report and need to add filter using javascript.

```
var basicFilter = {
                $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
                target: {
                    table: table,
                    column: column
                },
                operator: 'is',
                values: [value]
            };
```

above is the filter target for table and column. What should I pass to filter calculated fields?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Your [value] should be set of values in comma separted like below
["A","B","C",...etc]
Hope this will help, it worked for me.